# How to remove characters from an NSString and replace with spaces?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsrange

I have a NSString:

```
NSString *string1 = @"http://example.com/this-is-an-example-post"
```

By removing a range of characteres I have substringed it to:

```
NSString *string2 = @"this-is-an-example-post"
```

But I am struggling to get it into the form of:

```
NSString *string3 = @"this is an example post"
```

Any help? Much appreciated.

Comment: `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: withString:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example this way

```
string3 = [string2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@" "];
```

Comment: @CescSergey: Probably because a simple lookup of the NSString documentation would have solved your problem.